# Checked persistency on Checkbox using React Hook Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a Checkbox component looking like this:

```
...
{values.map((value) => (
  <div key={value}>
    <div
      className={`checkbox ${
        checked && checked.includes(value) && "checked"
      }`}
    >
      <div className="checkbox__box">
        <input
          {...register(name, {
            required: required,
            validate: CustomValidation,
          })}
          id={name + value}
          type="checkbox"
          name={name}
          value={value}
          defaultChecked={defaultData === value}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <label htmlFor={name + value}>
      <FormattedMessage id={value} />
    </label>
  </div>
))}
```

As you can see, the component relays on a `checked` prop array to add the `checked` class to the single checkbox element.

The component is being called like so:

```
<Checkbox
  values={SourceOfFundsList}
  name="source_of_funds__list"
  md={12}
  register={register}
  errors={errors}
  defaultData={
    props.data.dataTree.customer.source_of_funds.source_of_funds__list
  }
  checked={source_of_funds__list__checked}
/>
```

The `checked` props is populated by watching the form state, like so:

```
const source_of_funds__list__checked = watch("source_of_funds__list");
```

This works as expected, adding the class to every item of the Checkbox once it is clicked. It also logs in the console correctly, by using `useEffect`, like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(source_of_funds__list__checked);
}, [source_of_funds__list__checked]);
```

The problem arises when I move to another route, and then I come back.

When I come back to the page, 2 things happen:

- The state is persistent, and when inspecting the component, the `defaultData` contains the correct array with the checked items
- The `checked` array is undefined, and therefore the UI doesn't display the correct state (all checkboxes looked unchecked, as class is not applied)

I have tried to add a second `useEffect` to populate the `checked` array on load, if the defaultData is there to start with, and it consoles correctly, but still the classes are not applied.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.data.dataTree.customer.source_of_funds.source_of_funds__list) {
  
      source_of_funds__list__checked =
        props.data.dataTree.customer.source_of_funds.source_of_funds__list;
    
    }

    console.log("source_of_funds__list__checked", source_of_funds__list__checked);
}, []);
```

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the render cycle and some mistake on my use of `useEffect`.

Any pointers on what could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misuse the react hook form. inside the useffect, use the 'setValue' to update the initial array, and instead of using 'watch', replace it with 'useWatch'. Try it out, hope it helps you!

Comment: Great answer! I think it helps to highlight code by surrounding it with "`" or "```" for code blocks, but I left yours unchanged, because I think it was straight to the point.